# Can we modify ConverterUtil.java file while creating stubs

Tags: apache-axis

I have a issue with ConverterUtil.java file "convertToString" method. This method is used by stubs and it tries to convert the date into string. The problem i have is when it tries to convert the date which is in improper format axis error occurs and we are unable to recieve the response.

Acutally converterutil is doing fine as when it receives the dateTimestamp is not correct & it has letter "T" between date & time something like "04-12-2010T00:00:00". We cannot change the how we received the format we recieve the date time unfortunately.

We want to override the converterUtil's "convertToString" method but it is static class so we cannot override. Repackaging of Axis2.jar is not good idea because we do want to do it. Also maven dependency is not helping us override the convertUtil as stub is used as JAR in our project & we already tried maven dependency but it is not over help.

ConverterUtil is used in the response class of the stub & we want to override it. So is it possible to modify wsdl2java in some way that it ignores the ConverterUtil file and start using custom file. In other words is it possible to control how stubs are actually generated.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not clear with your question.
Let me explain Are you a consumer? Is the webservice returning a date which you don't want?
 If the answer is yes then alter the XMl message before it is going to hit the stub file.
   What you can do go to your axis2.xml file and go to the section **phases**  after security phase declare your own phase like

```
 <phase name="Validator">
        <handler name="DateValidator"
                 class="com.validator.DateHandler"/>
    </phase>
```

create a class called DateHandler and try to alter the value by extracting the xml from the SOAPContext.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek for your time. Yes i am consumer & i cannot change the XML message as it is coming from somewhere else where i have no control. So i cannot ask axis to ignore it. Axis generated the stubs using wsdl2java utitlity & it creates the different supporting java against the wsdl. I want to control the file generated or rewrite the methods that are generated dynamically